# pleasetell me my error

Tags: c, file-io, queue, fopen

this code is supposed to "open" the saved txt file that is inputted and can be edited by the user...

for example, i saved "Bob 12345 17" and "Max 123456 18" in save.txt... when i open the file file and print all in my linked list, it only shows: "Max 123456 18"... and whenever i close my program and i try to open save.txt first without overwriting on it, it doesnt show anything when i print all in my linked list...

```
FILE* open;
char filenameopen[100];

printf ("\nType the name of the file you want to open: ");
scanf ("%s", filenameopen);
printf ("\n");

open = fopen (filenameopen, "r");
if (filenameopen == NULL)
    printf ("No such file exists\n\n");
else
{   
    phonebook_t *openentry = (phonebook_t*) malloc (sizeof(phonebook_t));
    openentry = head;

    while (1)
    {
        fscanf (open, "%s %s %d", openentry -> name, openentry -> tel, &openentry -> age);
        if (feof (open))
        {
            openentry -> next = NULL;
            break;
        }
        openentry -> next = (phonebook_t*) malloc (sizeof(phonebook_t)); 
        openentry = openentry -> next;  
    }

    fclose(open);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Where do you think the problem is?

Comment: @Mike I tried declaring openentry = head... my compiler says: exe has stopped working... i really dont know where the bug is... i tried debugging it earlier

Comment: Could you update your code with your edit; it's likely you put the `head` assignment in the wrong place.

Comment: Side note: `if (filenameopen == NULL)` should be `if (open == NULL)`

Comment: Side note: `phonebook_t *openentry = malloc(sizeof(*openentry))` is much more maintainable (and readable) than `phonebook_t *openentry = (phonebook_t*) malloc (sizeof(phonebook_t));`

Comment: @Shahbaz thanks! but still have some bugs...

Comment: @Evert i updated it already :)

Comment: Doing `phonebook_t *openentry = malloc(sizeof(*openentry))` will allocate a memory block to hold a pointer to a `struct phonebook_t`, not a `struct phonebook_t` ... that will definitely cause issues.

Comment: To the closers: this is imo a real question, even it's not overly clear. But it looks like instead of asking for clarification, people just close it...

Comment: Two mistakes: you haven't declared `head` (i.e., set the type), and you assign `openentry` to `head`: it should be the other way around. To help with these kind of things, draw diagrams: boxes that contain the various pointers, with arrows connecting them, and then a diagram for each step. Tedious, but it makes things very clear.

Comment: @jason, no it doesn't. `sizeof(*openentry)` is the size of where `openentry` points to, which is `phonebook_t`. If you write `malloc(sizeof(openentry))` _then_ it would allocate memory for just a pointer. Maybe you missed the `*`?

Comment: @Shahbaz : Yep, I mixed up the dereferencing operation on the right-hand-side of the assignment operator with the original pointer declaration on the left.  So you're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in your `while` loop you lose the head of the linked list when you assign it to the next node ... so there is no way you're going to be able to print the entire list once you're done with the loop.

Adjust your code to something like this:

```
//declare you head-pointer outside the scope of the if-statement
phonebook_t *ll_head = (phonebook_t*) malloc (sizeof(phonebook_t));

if (...)
{
    //...
}
else
{
    //assign a temporary pointer to use in your while-loop
    phonebook_t* openentry = ll_head;

    //...rest of your code
}
```

Now when you're done with the while-loop, start printing from `ll_head` as it's still pointing to the start of the linked list, not the last node.

Comment: i tried declaring openentry = head before the while loop... my compiler says: exe has stopped working...

Comment: i declared these in my struct:  char name[30]; 
 char tel[15]; 
 int age; 
 struct phonebook* next; 
 struct phonebook* previous;

Comment: Wow, this is a double-linked list?  ... Why?

Comment: @Jason: where does it say *double*? It's just a (very simple) linked list. And I guess for the why: just practice / learning effort.